# Timespan every year before birthday

Tags: r

Data:

```
 DB <- data.frame(orderID  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),     
   orderDate = c("1.1.14","16.3.14","11.5.14","21.6.14","29.7.14", 
        "2.8.14","21.9.14","4.10.14","30.11.14","2.1.15"),  
   itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),  
   price = c(29.90, 39.90, 29.90, 19.90, 49.90, 9.90, 29.90, 39.90, 
              14.90, 19.90),
   customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
   dateofbirth = c("12.1.67","14.10.82","6.8.87","12.1.67","12.1.67",
           "6.8.87","14.10.82","14.10.82","12.1.67","12.1.67")
```

Expected outcome:

```
orderedinatimespan2weeksbeforebirthday = c("Yes", "No", "No", "No",
     "No", "Yes", "No"  , "Yes", "No", "Yes")
```

Hi guys,
hope you made it well into the new year ;) 
unfortunately the new year brought me some new problems I´m not able to solve alone - so I would be very pleased if you peeps help me again :) In the data set every order got its own id and every registered user has his unique customerID. Every customer can order items (with ItemIDs), which got specific prices. User has his/her date of birth written in the data bank(as you can see above :D ) I want to mark the orders which happened in a time span of 2 weeks before his/her bithday or on his/her birthday with a "Yes" and orders at the rest of the year with a "No". Additionally the "formula" should not only work for this year-it should also work for orders during the next years. (2016 etc.)  I also want to add the results as new columns in my existing data set (orderedinatimespan2weeksbeforebirthday)...

Tried it already like this, but the span function is not working when I use only days and month without a year...

```
DB$dateOfBirth <- as.Date(DB$dateOfBirth) 
DB$Birthday1 <- format(as.Date(DB$dateofbirth), "%m-%d")
DB$Birthday2 <- DB$dateOfBirth-ddays(14)
DB$Birthday3 <- format(as.Date(DB$Birthday2), "%m-%d")
DB$Birthday3 <- format(as.Date(DB$Birthday3), "%y-%m-%d")
DB$spanBirthday <- new_interval (ymd(DB$Birthday2), ymd(mydata$Birthday1))
```

Hope your able to show me what´s wrong or show me another posibility to solve the prob....

Cheers and THX!

Comment: Perhaps change the `year` of birthday  to the `year` of the order (as a separate column)

Comment: I don´t really understand what you mean

Comment: Your post says that it won't work `without a year`, so you could make the `year` part same for the order and `birthday`

Comment: ah,ok:how can I do it?

Comment: I accepted every solution so far-and I´m very grateful for every one

Comment: I updated the post based on the new format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to change the "year" part of the "dateofbirth" as that of the "orderDate" and then check whether the `DOB1` lies within "2 weeks" of "orderDate".  Use `sub` to remove the "day/month" from the "orderDate", `strsplit` the "dateofbirth" column, replace the "3rd" element ("year") with the "year" from "orderDate".  This can be done with "mapply".  Convert to "date" class and do the logical operation `<`, which returns "TRUE/FALSE".  If you need to convert that to "Yes/No", add "1" to the result to get a numeric index of "1/2" and replace with "Yes/No".

```
toChange <- sub('.*\\.', '', DB$orderDate)
DOB <- mapply(function(x,y) {x[3]<-y; paste(x,collapse=".")}, 
           strsplit(as.character(DB$dateofbirth),'[.]'), toChange)
DOB1 <- as.Date(DOB, '%d.%m.%y')
orderDate <- as.Date(DB$orderDate, '%d.%m.%y')
c('No', 'Yes')[(orderDate-12 <DOB1 & DOB1 <= orderDate+12)+1]
#[1] "Yes" "No"  "No"  "No"  "No"  "Yes" "No"  "Yes" "No"  "Yes"
```

If you need to change for different "orderDate", wrapping it in a function would be easier

```
ordertimeSpan <- function(data, orderCol, DOBCol){
 toChange <- sub('.*\\.', '', data[,orderCol])
 DOB <- mapply(function(x,y){x[3] <- y; paste(x,collapse='.')}, 
     strsplit(as.character(data[,DOBCol]),'[.]'), toChange)
 DOB1 <- as.Date(DOB, '%d.%m.%y')
 orderDate <- as.Date(data[,orderCol], '%d.%m.%y')
 c('No', 'Yes')[(orderDate-12 < DOB1 & DOB1 <= orderDate+12)+1]
 }

 ordertimeSpan(DB, 'orderDate', 'dateofbirth')
 #[1] "Yes" "No"  "No"  "No"  "No"  "Yes" "No"  "Yes" "No"  "Yes"
```

#### Update

If the "dates" are already in the `%Y-%m-%d` format, ie.

```
 DB$orderDate <- as.Date(DB$orderDate, '%d.%m.%y')
 DB$dateofbirth <- as.Date(DB$dateofbirth, '%d.%m.%y')
 #in the present datatset, "dateofbirth" would end up in "year" 2067, etc by converting to 'Date' class, which could be corrected .  But, that is not the main focus here..

toChange <- format(DB$orderDate, '%Y')
DOB <- mapply(function(x,y) {x[1]<-y; as.Date(paste(x,collapse="-"))}, 
          strsplit(as.character(DB$dateofbirth),'[-]'), toChange)
 orderDate <- DB$orderDate
 c('No', 'Yes')[(orderDate-12 <DOB & DOB <= orderDate+12)+1]
#[1] "Yes" "No"  "No"  "No"  "No"  "Yes" "No"  "Yes" "No"  "Yes"
```

Comment: I think I made an mistake- the date format for dateofbirth and orderDate is: 2012-04-07

Comment: what´t the difference here now?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Then you have to change the format accordingly. ie. `%Y-%m-%d` in the `orderDate`

Comment: Tried it a few times- and it finally meet my needs! Thank´s a lottle! :)